# Spring AOP: @within behavior when extending classes

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have an annotation which will be used on extended placeholder classes. Basically, our service will have an implementation, and we will have an explicit extension which will be annotated. I am not sure what the problem is, but `@within` is not invoking the code whereas `@target` is.

Here is a sample code - https://github.com/sahil-ag/Spring-AOP-Sample

```
@Component
public BaseClass { public void getData() {return "";}}

@SampleAnnotation
@Component
public DerivedClass extends BaseClass {}
```

Here if we now use a `@within(SampleAnnotation)` pointcut, we will not be able to intercept the `getData()` when called from a derived class bean.

Comment: Please don't let people navigate away from your question, instead add some code to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The `@within` Annotation is used when you want to define a class where the pointcuts are located in. So make sure that your within-clause looks like:

```
@within(@MyAnnotation *)
```

The '*' is used to say *any* class. This is the part you are missing in your example.

Another approach would be to use the `@annotation` pointcut:

```
@Annotation(@MyAnnotation)
```

---

Official documentation:

https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html

Comment: I am using Spring Aspects.
So, @Annotation pointcut is used only for methods with SampleAnnotation.
I also tries using `within(@SampleAnnotation *)` but that had similar behavior. I also tried `@within(SampleAnnotation *)` and `@within(@SampleAnnotation *)` but both threw runtime exception - `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed:`

Comment: @annotation is working for only method level point cuts, meaning if the annotation is at class level, those methods are not intercepted.